# Shared library standard make flags variable?

Tags: linux, makefile

Think SAT format question:

CFLAGS is to compilation
and
LDFLAGS is to link
as
??????? is to a shared (.so) link

Thanks greatly!!!

Comment: Did a little more research in the gnu make doc and I guess I'm looking for the "predefined implicit rule" for .so files so I can find what variable it uses.  Funny the gnu make doc does not suggest that there IS one for .so, but at the same time I've got this makefile that is linking a .so without any includes or .so rules defined!

Comment: Forget it! I'm 99% sure that in fact there isn't a predefined implicit rule and therefore no default variable name!!!

Comment: You can make `make` spit out the implicit rules it uses (along with a lot of other info) with the `-p` option.

Answer (score 0):

Tought one, maybe `SHARED_LDFLAGS`.